# Async/await in Web.API 2 Controllers Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have controller with actions like below:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetData()
{
    var resultSet = await Task.Run(()=>{Repository.GetRecords();});
    if(resultSet==null)
    {
        return ErrorResponse(){Message = Repository.LastErrorMessage};
    }
    return Ok(resultSet);
}
```

`Repository.GetData` is using ODBC driver for getting data from Database.
Is this pattern ok for WEB.API Action or it will harm the performance by creating separate Task for getting Data?

Comment: Don't use `Task.Run` for I/O operations. Use the proper asynchronous methods in `GetRecords()`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Repository is not using any Framework and there are not any asynchronous methods. So it would be better to take async/await to Repository?

Comment: If there are no asynchronous method then don't use asynchronous calls. Creating a thread to wait on an I/O operation is a waste.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ok, thank you.